# Getting event-log in powershell

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am using powershell for searching specific errors of application. My code is working, but in output are duplicate eventID, message and so on.I need only one kind of message. Is it possible?

```
$date=(Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
$file = New-item -type file "C:\event.txt" -force
Get-EventLog -LogName 01-D -EntryType Error -After $date | 
Where {$_.EventId -eq 1 -or $_.EventId -in 3..13371 -or $_.EventId -in 13373..21003 -or $_.EventId -in 21005..21007 -or $_.EventId -in 21009..49498 -or $_.EventId -in 49500..53519 -or $_.EventId -in 53521..62200 -or $_.EventId -in 62202..64494 -or $_.EventId -in 64496..99999 -and $_.EventId -ne 21050} | 
Sort-Object eventid | format-list -Property EventId,MachineName,EntryType, Message | out-file $file -Encoding default
```

Comment: use the `-unique` parameter of [select-object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use either select-object with -unique parameter or group-object with -noelements parameters which allow you to count the occurences of each event